# С помощью vba(word) Реализовать поиск факториала числа Число должно задаваться в строковом виде как числительное (максимальное значение 100)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Реализовать поиск факториала числа
– Число должно задаваться в строковом виде как числительное (максимальное значение 100). Числительное может быть на русском или английском(на своё усмотрение). Факториал такого числа, конечно, не посчитается, но парсер должен уметь преобразовать числительное. Допустима строка на русском или английском языках.
– Число должно быть задано через компонент InputBox.
– Вывод результата – первой строкой на активном листе документа:
•Шрифт Arial
•Размер 16 pt.
•Начертание: курсив.
Ну я максимум что смог реализовать обычный поиск факториала.

```
Sub z3()
Dim n As Integer
Dim n2 As Integer
Dim nf As Long
n = InputBox("Введите число для вычисления факториала")

n2 = n
nf = 1
If n2 > 1 Then
    Do While n2 > 1
        nf = nf * n2
            n2 = n2 - 1
    Loop
End If
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 16
    .Italic = True
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter text:=(nf) & " "
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, ввод будет "сорок два"

Comment: *Реализовать поиск факториала числа* Поиск, извините, ГДЕ?

Comment: @MBo "три дюжины" ;)

Comment: Под реализовать поиск факториала имеется ввиду, что строка вводится в inputbox

Comment: Да, нужно вводить в стиле: сорок два, пять, восемь.